# How to get all first records (ordered by a column) of a nested one to many relationship in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, greatest-n-per-group

I've some nested one to many relationship as follows:

`Enquiry` hasMany `Item`

`Item` hasMany `Component`

`Component` hasMany `Process`

Imagine I have the `Enquiry` Model loaded already. Now I would like to access the first `Process` of each `Component` of each `Item` ordered by a column in `Process` called `order`

[image: This picture might show it better (Sorry for using ERD like this)]

This picture might show it better (Sorry for using ERD like this)

What I've got so far is something like this:

```
$enquiry->items->load(['components' => function($query) {
    $query->with(['processes' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('order')->limit(1)
    }]);
}])->get();
```

but it only gives me the top process, not the top `Process` of each `Component` of each `Item` belonging to the given `Enquiry`.

Any help would be appreciated. And ofcourse any help regarding a better title would be much appreciated as well. Thank you.

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the SQL.

Comment: @Strawberry you mean tags?

Comment: No. I mean I wouldn't bother with any of this laravel/eloquent stuff until I had a working query

Comment: @Strawberry Well It can go both ways. I don't know how to do it in SQL either. If you have a solution in SQL I can use it either way.

Comment: Try: `$query->where('id', DB::raw('select min(processes.id) from processes where processes.component_id = components.id'));`

Comment: For SQL - see this: [sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel well it didn't work. having min and max in DB::raw I don't know but it gives syntax error I tried different ways the link you provided was really helpful.but now I'm basically struggling with syntax problems

Comment: `$query->where('order', DB::raw('(select min(p.order) from processes p where p.component_id = processes.component_id)'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @PaulSpiegel Link it directed me to the right way. This is how I did it with subqueries in Laravel using QueryBuilder.

```
$subQuery = DB::table('processes as icp')
            ->selectRaw('min(icp.order), icp.*')
            ->groupBy('icp.component_id');

$firstProcesses = DB::table('enquiries as enq')
            ->where('enq.id', $enquiry->id)
            ->join('items', 'items.enquiry_id', 'enq.id')
            ->join('components as ic', 'ic.item_id', 'items.id')
            ->joinSub($subQuery, 'icp', function ($join) {
                $join->on('ic.id', 'icp.component_id');
            })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you define a relationship on your Component model like this:

```php
class Component {
    public function firstProcess() {
        return $this->hasMany(Process::class)->orderBy('order')->take(1);
    }
}
```

And then do something like this:

```php
$enquiry->load('items.components.firstProcess');
```

Then you should be able to access that property on each of your components:

```php
foreach ($enquiry->items as $item) {
    foreach($item->components as $component) {
        print_r($component->firstProcess);
    }
}
```

I didnt test this code.

Comment: I tried that it actually only works on the first process of the first component of the first item. same as my own way of getting it. It doesn't give all first processes.

Comment: Please don't write guesses as answer.